# Linear regression in R (normal and logarithmic data)

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression, curve-fitting, power-law

I want to carry out a linear regression in R for data in a normal and in a double logarithmic plot.

For **normal data** the dataset might be the follwing:

```
lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
plot (lin$x, lin$y)
```

There I want to calculate draw a line for the linear regression only of the datapoints 2, 3 and 4.

For **double logarithmic data** the dataset might be the following:

```
data = data.frame(
    x=c(1:15),
    y=c(
        1.000, 0.742, 0.623, 0.550, 0.500, 0.462, 0.433,
        0.051, 0.043, 0.037, 0.032, 0.028, 0.025, 0.022, 0.020
      )
    )
plot (data$x, data$y, log="xy")
```

Here I want to draw the regression line for the datasets 1:7 and for 8:15.

Ho can I calculate the *slope* and the *y-offset* als well as parameters for the fit (*R^2*, *p-value*)?

How is it done for normal and for logarithmic data?

Thanks for you help,

Sven

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In R, linear least squares models are fitted via the `lm()` function. Using the formula interface we can use the `subset` argument to select the data points used to fit the actual model, for example:

```
lin <- data.frame(x = c(0:6), y = c(0.3, 0.1, 0.9, 3.1, 5, 4.9, 6.2))
linm <- lm(y ~ x, data = lin, subset = 2:4)
```

giving:

```
R> linm

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = lin, subset = 2:4)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     -1.633        1.500  

R> fitted(linm)
         2          3          4 
-0.1333333  1.3666667  2.8666667
```

As for the double log, you have two choices I guess; i) estimate two separate models as we did above, or ii) estimate via ANCOVA. The log transformation is done in the formula using `log()`.

Via two separate models:

```
logm1 <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data = dat, subset = 1:7)
logm2 <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data = dat, subset = 8:15)
```

Or via ANCOVA, where we need an indicator variable

```
dat <- transform(dat, ind = factor(1:15 <= 7))
logm3 <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x) * ind, data = dat)
```

You might ask if these two approaches are equivalent? Well they are and we can show this via the model coefficients.

```
R> coef(logm1)
  (Intercept)        log(x) 
-0.0001487042 -0.4305802355 
R> coef(logm2)
(Intercept)      log(x) 
  0.1428293  -1.4966954
```

So the two slopes are -0.4306 and -1.4967 for the separate models. The coefficients for the ANCOVA model are:

```
R> coef(logm3)
   (Intercept)         log(x)        indTRUE log(x):indTRUE 
     0.1428293     -1.4966954     -0.1429780      1.0661152
```

How do we reconcile the two? Well the way I set up `ind`, `logm3` is parametrised to give more directly values estimated from `logm2`; the intercepts of `logm2` and `logm3` are the same, as are the coefficients for `log(x)`. To get the values equivalent to the coefficients 
of `logm1`, we need to do a manipulation, first for the intercept:

```
R> coefs[1] + coefs[3]
  (Intercept) 
-0.0001487042
```

where the coefficient for `indTRUE` is the difference in the mean of group 1 over the mean of group 2. And for the slope:

```
R> coefs[2] + coefs[4]
    log(x) 
-0.4305802
```

which is the same as we got for `logm1` and is based on the slope for group 2 (`coefs[2]`) modified by the difference in slope for group 1 (`coefs[4]`).

As for plotting, an easy way is via `abline()` for simple models. E.g. for the normal data example:

```
plot(y ~ x, data = lin)
abline(linm)
```

For the log data we might need to be a bit more creative, and the general solution here is to predict over the range of data and plot the predictions:

```
pdat <- with(dat, data.frame(x = seq(from = head(x, 1), to = tail(x,1), 
                                     by = 0.1))
pdat <- transform(pdat, yhat = c(predict(logm1, pdat[1:70,, drop = FALSE]), 
                                 predict(logm2, pdat[71:141,, drop = FALSE])))
```

Which can plot on the original scale, by exponentiating `yhat`

```
plot(y ~ x, data = dat)
lines(exp(yhat) ~ x, dat = pdat, subset = 1:70, col = "red")
lines(exp(yhat) ~ x, dat = pdat, subset = 71:141, col = "blue")
```

or on the log scale:

```
plot(log(y) ~ log(x), data = dat)
lines(yhat ~ log(x), dat = pdat, subset = 1:70, col = "red")
lines(yhat ~ log(x), dat = pdat, subset = 71:141, col = "blue")
```

For example...

This general solution works well for the more complex ANCOVA model too. Here I create a new pdat as before and add in an indicator

```
pdat <- with(dat, data.frame(x = seq(from = head(x, 1), to = tail(x,1), 
                                     by = 0.1)[1:140],
                             ind = factor(rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), each = 70))))
pdat <- transform(pdat, yhat = predict(logm3, pdat))
```

Notice how we get all the predictions we want from the single call to `predict()` because of the use of ANCOVA to fit `logm3`. We can now plot as before:

```
plot(y ~ x, data = dat)
lines(exp(yhat) ~ x, dat = pdat, subset = 1:70, col = "red")
lines(exp(yhat) ~ x, dat = pdat, subset = 71:141, col = "blue")
```

Comment: How can I get a single number ouf of a named num? `str(coef(daten_fit))` gives: 
`Named num 0.8
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "x"`, but is it somehow possible to ask coef to get the value with the name "x". I tried different thinks like `coeff(daten_fit)$x` or `coeff(daten_fit)[1]` or `attr(coeff(daten_fit), "x")`,... but nothing worked. Is it not possible to get the value by name?

Comment: @Sven it is a named numeric vector. Note that it is `coef()` with one "f" not `coeff()` with two. `coef(logm2)["(Intercept)"]` and `coef(logm2)["log(x)"]` work for me on the `logm2` object from my answer. You can't use `$` on an atomic vector (a vector of one basic type), it only works on lists (and data frames which of course are lists).

Answer (score 3):

```
#Split the data into two groups
data1 <- data[1:7, ]
data2 <- data[8:15, ]

#Perform the regression
model1 <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data1)
model2 <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x), data2)
summary(model1)
summary(model2)

#Plot it
with(data, plot(x, y, log="xy"))
lines(1:7, exp(predict(model1, data.frame(x = 1:7))))
lines(8:15, exp(predict(model2, data.frame(x = 8:15))))
```

In general, splitting the data into different groups and running different models on different subsets is unusual, and probably bad form.  You may want to consider adding a grouping variable

```
data$group <- factor(rep(letters[1:2], times = 7:8))
```

and running some sort of model on the whole dataset, e.g.,

```
model_all <- lm(log(y) ~ log(x) * group, data)
summary(model_all)
```